# How to multiply multiple column dataframe by another single column df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiplication

I'm trying to multiply two dataframes:(3868 rows x 758 columns) and (3868 rows x 1 column)

```
free_float = pd.DataFrame(free_float)

weights = pd.DataFrame(weights )

columns = weights.columns

weights[columns] *= free_float['A']
```

Above codes give me error: `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (14961424,) (3868,)`.

Comment: what are your shapes? also, why not use numpy arrays directly instead of dataframes?

Comment: Seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

With pandas you need to specify `.values` to multiply your dataframe:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,3868))
df2=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(3868,758)))
pd.DataFrame(df1.values*df2.values)
```